# Myers' Fast bit-vector algorithm in plain English?

Tags: algorithms, strings

Inspired by this [question on Suffix Trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452701/ukkonens-suffix-tree-algorithm-in-plain-english), and the fabulous winning answer, I would hereby ask for a similar explanation of Myers' [Fast Bit-Vector Algorithm for Approximate String
Matching Based on Dynamic Programming](http://www.gersteinlab.org/courses/452/09-spring/pdf/Myers.pdf).

Comment: I am very wary of such questions. There are things "plain English" is not sufficient for.

Comment: The paper on Ukkonen's algorithm for building suffix trees in linear time is pretty complex too, but jogajapan managed to translate it to "plain English" beautifully.

Comment: I've been studying string alignment algos recently, and would love to see this too.